# Landau levels in ferromagnets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics

Consider a spontaneously magnetised (uniformly) conducting ferromagnet. Now suppose that there is no external magnetic field. The question is as follows: will the motion of electrons be quantized via Landau levels because of intrinsic magnetic field of the magnet?

On the first sight, it should be - the magnetisation creates magnetic field that is uniform *in average* and nothing seems to be distinct from the case of electrons in actual uniform magnetic field.

However, it is not as simple as it sounds. First of all, on the atomic scale the field in the magnet is highly non-uniform. Secondly, there might be some impurities that affect orbital motion of electrons, and so on.

So, does the magnetisation cause any changes in orbital motion of electrons, compared to a simple conductor? Is it possible to speak about the band structure in ferromagnets if the Landau quantization actually happens?